# Linkage error - Eigen and Visual studio 2015

Tags: c++, visual-c++, eigen

Dear C++ and Visual Studio developers,

I'm having a linkage problem with the Eigen library in Visual Studio 2015. Until now, I've followed all the solution purposes to link it, i.e. associated the necesssary folder to the external include of the project (Additional Include Directories ), without sucess. Despite of that, the library and the associated imports and namespaces keep not being recognized.

It would be helpful if one of you could give another possibility to solve it.

I thank you for the help and I'm looking forward for the answer.

Best regards.

PS.: As usual, sorry for the bad english. I'm not a native speaker.

Comment: Post the actual error message you're getting. Also, Eigen is a header-only library, so there is nothing to link.

Comment: Eigen is one of the simplest libraries when it comes to include them in your project. You need just to add the correct path, therefore, you need to tell us how did you  include the path.

Comment: I've expressed myself wrong when I've said "error". The include of the library just didn't work well. I've followed the following procedure:

"Project Properties > C/C++ > Additional Directories >" and added the EIGEN_DIR I've added to the windows path.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's say you've downloaded the Eigen header files. In my case,

```
D:\CPP_Libraries\Eigen_3.2.4
```

Inside the aforementioned folder is

[image]

I will use command prompt for the sake of simplicity. Since Eigen library is a bunch of header files, we need to include the path. Now invoke the command prompt of visual studio and type

```
cl /EHsc main.cpp /Fetest.exe /I D:\CPP_Libraries\Eigen_3.2.4
```

For `main.cpp`,

```
#include <iostream>
#include <Eigen/Dense>

int main()
{
   //@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@
   Eigen::MatrixXd m(2,2);
   m(0,0) = 3;
   m(1,0) = 2.5;
   m(0,1) = -1;
   m(1,1) = m(1,0) + m(0,1);
   std::cout << " m = \n"       << m       << std::endl << std::endl;
   std::cout << " m.inv() = \n" << m.inverse() << std::endl << std::endl;
   //@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@
   Eigen::MatrixXd b(3,3);
   b << 1, 2, 3,
        4, 5, 6,
        7, 8, 9;
    std::cout << " b = \n" << b  << std::endl << std::endl;
   //@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@
  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Over the "Additional Include Directories" select: Platform: all platforms (or x64, x86) and in configuration: all configurations (to select debug and release modes)